# How do I create a recurring event on Google Calendar API?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a meeting every Monday to Friday at 8:00, but I'm having this problem and I can't solve it.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const { authenticate } = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    const res = await calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    const event = {
        'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
        'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
        'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'recurrence': [
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ],
        'attendees': [
            { 'email': 'lpage@example.com' },
            { 'email': 'sbrin@example.com' },
        ],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': false,
            'overrides': [
                { 'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60 },
                { 'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10 },
            ],
        },
    };

    calendar.events.insert({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: event,
    }, function (err, event) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
    });
}

authorize().then(listEvents).catch(console.error);
```

I tried to read the google guide, I added all kind of permissions on the application and on the developer users but it didn't let me do anything, I tried to do everything but it didn't work, I would just like some help thanks

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting from Calendar's API?

Comment: There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Insufficient Permission